# Cordova on Android 4.0.4 HTML not refreshing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am running a Cordova app on an old Android tablet(4.0.4, old but should be supported). When I press somewhere on the screen the changes appears. When I change the HTML it doesn't render the changes on the screen. It works on iOS, in the browser and in newer android versions.

```
    var htmlTmp = $.get('templates/login.temp.html', function (res) {
        var tmp = _.template(res);
        $('#app').empty().append(tmp);
```

UPDATE:

These lines caused the html not to render:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

I don't know why, perhaps there is a problem with webkit on older android devices.

Answer (score 0):

On old Android browsers this is a common problem, where the view will not refresh unless you force the browser to repaint the screen.
See if

`setTimeout(function(){$('#app').empty().append(tmp);},100)`

works for you.
Another options is to hide and show the element:

$('#app').hide();

$('#app').get(0).offsetHeight;

$('#app').show();

If none of these works then try

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

In general you need to do something to repaint your view.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. I tried both, and with different interval as well. The only thing that has worked so far is letting one of my text inputs have autofocus-property, and this is not what i want for all of my views.

Comment: damn! try with $(window).trigger('resize');

Comment: Didn't work either :( Thanks for the great ideas though, unfortunately the only thing that makes the view visible is when I click anywhere on the main container(basically anywhere on the screen). If an alert is shown the html is rendered when I dismiss it as well.